# Application Rejected because for some permission issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

Google rejected the app by saying **Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Default Assistant handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Backup and restore for users}. Please remove these permissions from your app.**

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


<permission
    android:name="com.titan.machine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.titan.machine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Yes because of this Permission you're got rejected 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
Are you using something in your app related to this permission in your app

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, In my application about us page, I added a contact number and on clicking it deafult call dialer should open. For this purpose I use this permission

Comment: you can implement below code and your app will be successfully published on Google Play Store.

Comment: @PujaSingh If You are opening an External Dialer you don't need this permission

Comment: It says you have declared the permission but havent been using the permissions. Show your code where you are making use of these functionality.

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274)

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your application on Google play store after implementing this code Snippet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed their permission policy for SMS/Call Log permissions. Only SMS apps and Calling apps can access these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

You can see these links for your clarifications 
(https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html

https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827)

you can use new SMS retriever API for OTP (https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/)